# How to do response payload logging and conversion in spring integration.?

Tags: spring-integration

I have set expectedResponseType(MyClass.class). So OutboundGateway is converting the message into my response class type and returning to me. I want to log the payload as well for debugging purpose along with the conversion.

How to do this response payload logging and conversion.?

I could do it by expecting the response as String and later convert into my class using marshallers. Is there any simpler way that can be used for all my outbound gateways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `expectedResponseType(MyClass.class)` is translated to the

```
httpResponse = this.restTemplate.exchange(realUri, httpMethod, httpRequest, (Class<?>) expectedResponseType);
```

where the last one does this:

```
public ResponseEntityResponseExtractor(Type responseType) {
    if (responseType != null && Void.class != responseType) {
        this.delegate = new HttpMessageConverterExtractor<T>(responseType, 
                                                  getMessageConverters(), logger);
    }
    else {
        this.delegate = null;
    }
}
```

As you see it is copying its own `logger` to the `HttpMessageConverterExtractor`.

So, I think you can achieve some good result for your `logging` requirements switching on `DEBUG` (or even `TRACE`) for the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` category.

From other side you always can extend the `RestTemplate` a bit to make some hooks into it.

From the Spring Integration perspective we can do nothing. Because the whole hard conversion work is done in the `RestTemplate`.

Comment: Thank you. I failed to mention that logging i refer is I wanted to store the response information in database etc. We could see what is going and coming in the log4j logs. but we wanted to store it somewhere..

Comment: Well, as I said: you always can inherit from the `RestTemplate` and inject it into the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`.